# How to loop through all numbers in an object with unknown properties?

Tags: javascript, typescript, object, ecmascript-5

How to loop through all numbers in an object with an unknown structure? Say I want to create a function that converts all numbers in an object to their absolute value.

For example this type of object as input to that said function would work:

```
interface RandomType: {
    num: number;
    nums: number[];
    anyObj: any[];
}
```

Comment: could you show us the output desired ?

Comment: Iterate over the properties, check the type of the value. Number? -> `Math.abs()`; Object? -> Iterate over the properties -> ...; Array? -> iterate over the elements -> ...;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could iterate through all of the object's enumerable keys using a `for ... in` loop, though I would recommend using the [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) function. See example below:

```
declare const obj: randomType;
for (const k of Object.keys(obj)) {
  if (typeof obj[k] === 'number')
    obj[k] = Math.abs(obj[k]);
}
```